# How to show hidden toolbar with animation?

Tags: android, animation, show, toolbar

I want to show hidden toolbar with animation by clicking the button. I have found a good code for hiding and then showing toolbar:

Hide:

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(-toolbar.getBottom()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

Show:

```
toolbar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()).start();
```

But I need to show toolbar at first, so it should be hidden by the time I start animation.

I would be grateful for the help.

Comment: When the application starts use the **Show** code and when the animation is finished show the **Hide** code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the action bar on resume, before starting the animation :

If you are using the appcompat library,

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

else

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Toolbar visibility must be Invisible in this case?

Comment: Oops, I thought you want it to be visible by default. Edited the answer.